# Aws Base64 S3 http post bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to recreate the example from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

And the first step is to convert the policy to base64. So in this example

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

They say in base64 this should be

```
eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1LTEyLTMwVDEyOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLA0KICAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgICB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJzaWd2NGV4YW1wbGVidWNrZXQifSwNCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRrZXkiLCAidXNlci91c2VyMS8iXSwNCiAgICB7ImFjbCI6ICJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LA0KICAgIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cDovL3NpZ3Y0ZXhhbXBsZWJ1Y2tldC5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3NmdWxfdXBsb2FkLmh0bWwifSwNCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiLCAiaW1hZ2UvIl0sDQogICAgeyJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLXV1aWQiOiAiMTQzNjUxMjM2NTEyNzQifSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LXNlcnZlci1zaWRlLWVuY3J5cHRpb24iOiAiQUVTMjU2In0sDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkeC1hbXotbWV0YS10YWciLCAiIl0sDQoNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LWNyZWRlbnRpYWwiOiAiQUtJQUlPU0ZPRE5ON0VYQU1QTEUvMjAxNTEyMjkvdXMtZWFzdC0xL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LA0KICAgIHsieC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIjogIkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiAiMjAxNTEyMjlUMDAwMDAwWiIgfQ0KICBdDQp9
```

Using the following java code I am expecting to get the same

```
   String policy_document = "{ \"expiration\": \"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\",\n" +
            "  \"conditions\": [\n" +
            "    {\"bucket\": \"sigv4examplebucket\"},\n" +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"user/user1/\"],\n" +
            "    {\"acl\": \"public-read\"},\n" +
            "    {\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"},\n" +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"],\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-meta-uuid\": \"14365123651274\"},\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"},\n" +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$x-amz-meta-tag\", \"\"],\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-credential\": \"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"},\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},\n" +
            "    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20151229T000000Z\" }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";
    final byte[] authBytes = policy_document.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);

    System.out.println("base64 " + encoded);
```

but I am getting (which is different)

```
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
```

Any ideas? I've literally copied and pasted the policy from their page? Without this I can not recreate the example. When I decode both signatures using https://www.base64decode.org/ they return the same policy?? So what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this

`final String policy_document = "{ \"expiration\": \"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\",\r\n" + "  \"conditions\": [\r\n"
                + "    {\"bucket\": \"sigv4examplebucket\"},\r\n"
                + "    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"user/user1/\"],\r\n" + "    {\"acl\": \"public-read\"},\r\n"
                + "    {\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"},\r\n"
                + "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"],\r\n"
                + "    {\"x-amz-meta-uuid\": \"14365123651274\"},\r\n"
                + "    {\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"},\r\n"
                + "    [\"starts-with\", \"$x-amz-meta-tag\", \"\"],\r\n" + "\r\n"
                + "    {\"x-amz-credential\": \"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"},\r\n"
                + "    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},\r\n"
                + "    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20151229T000000Z\" }\r\n" + "  ]\r\n" + "}";`

After I replaced all \n with \r\n, I got the same base64 encoded value as the one provided by the AWS documentation page.

Comment: The irony... documentation states NOT to add carriage returns, yet adding them is what triggers a base64 match. Adding the returns worked for me too. Only I can't get my signatures to match the example on that page. I'm in Ruby.

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could. Encoding is obviously very sensitive to even small changes in spaces, characters. So If you are trying to get an exact output as in the AWS example you have to ensure that all blank spaces, characters etc are perfect. The above answer solves that. However, in a  real life example it doesn't matter since you are generating for your own string and not comparing with a hash of any other string.

Comment: The documentation on AWS now mentions `When you copy/paste the preceding policy, it should have carriage returns and new lines for your computed hash to match this value (ie. ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators). `